# Find string in log files and return extra characters

Tags: loops, python-3.x, filesystems

How can I get Python to loop through a directory and find a specific string in each file located within that directory, then output a summary of what it found?

I want to search the long files for the following string:
FIRMWARE_VERSION = "2.15"

Only, the firmware version can be different in each file. So I want the log file to report back with whatever version it finds.

```
import glob
import os

print("The following list contains the firmware version of each server.\n")

os.chdir( "LOGS\\" )
for file in glob.glob('*.log'):
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if 'FIRMWARE_VERSION = "' in contents:
        print (file + " = ???)
```

I was thinking I could use something like the following to return the extra characters but it's not working.

```
file[:+5]
```

I want the output to look something like this:

```
server1.web.com = FIRMWARE_VERSION = "2.16"
server2.web.com = FIRMWARE_VERSION = "3.01"
server3.web.com = FIRMWARE_VERSION = "1.26"
server4.web.com = FIRMWARE_VERSION = "4.1"
server5.web.com = FIRMWARE_VERSION = "3.50"
```

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: What you mean by *summary of what it found* exactly?

Comment: It's searching through a list of log files and each log file contains information about the firmware version. When it finds firmware version the script outputs to the screen the version of the firmware. It does this for each log file which is what I meant by summary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regex` for grub the text :

```
import re

for file in glob.glob('*.log'):
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    if 'FIRMWARE_VERSION = "' in contents:
        print (file + '='+ re.search(r'FIRMWARE_VERSION ="([\d.]+)"',contents).group(1))
```

In this case `re.search` will do the job! with searching the file content based on the following pattern :

```
r'FIRMWARE_VERSION ="([\d.]+)"'
```

that find a float number between two double quote!also you can use the following that match anything right after `FIRMWARE_VERSION`between two double quote.

```
r'FIRMWARE_VERSION =(".*")'
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @etho201 are you sure that the format of `FIRMWARE_VERSION = "2.15"` is correct? i mean the space before equation and ..

Comment: Ok that's working! Just needed to add a space between VERSION and the '=' character. Thanks!

Comment: r'FIRMWARE_VERSION = (".*")' is working. The other example (r'FIRMWARE_VERSION ="([\d\.]+)"') returned the NoneType error. Is it not recognizing the firmware as a double?

Comment: @etho201 maybe one of the versions is not float!

Comment: They all appear to be floats... "1.70" 
"1.80" 
"1.55" 
"2.06" 
"1.15" 
"1.28" 
"1.55" 
"2.15"